# How to stop toast & alertDialog losing focus on my EditText filter

Tags: java, android, filter

**UPDATE:**

**latest update - getChanges() method has been added.**

second update - I have added the whole of my ShoppingList.java class.

first update - After 2 people liking the question but no answers, I have opened up a bounty for this question.

**Question:**

I have had similar issues to this where I am unable to to re-filter my ListView once I start a new intent and then return back to the original page. This was solved with the use of an overiding the onResume() method and recalling my filter code from another filter method.

The latest issue Im having is should a dialogBuilder or a toast message be used on my app page, then once again the filter text is blanked i.e any text entered into my filter EditText is ignored by my filter.

Here are some screenshots to highlight the issue:

Loaded ListView of the items:

[image]

A search term is entered into the filter EditText and filter correctly:

[image]

The first item 'A' is edited to 'AB'. The toast message confirms the action:

[image]

**This is the issue, the dialogbuilder(which is how the item is edited) and toast message are complete, a new filter term is entered into the EditText and the filter no longer filters:**

[image]

Here is my filter code:

```
package com.example.flybaseapp;



    public class ShoppingList extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

Button AddItem;
Button showShop;
ListView showItems;
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
Long itemId;
TextView totalPrice;
String itemDescription;
int itemAmount;
int itemPrice;
EditText itemNameEdit;
DBHandlerShop getCons;
Dialog e1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.shoppinglistlayout);

    AddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);
    showShop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearchShops);

    showItems = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    totalPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalListPrice);

    AddItem.setOnClickListener(this);
    showShop.setOnClickListener(this);

    setList();

    int setPrice = updateTotal();
    totalPrice.setText(Integer.toString(setPrice));

    itemNameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputItemName);

    showItems.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    itemNameEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            showItems.refreshDrawableState();

        }

    });

    getCons = new DBHandlerShop(this, null, null);
    getCons.open();
    cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

            return getCons.getChanges((constraint.toString()));

        }

    });

    showItems.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View clickedAdd) {

    switch (clickedAdd.getId()) {

    case (R.id.btnAddItem):

        show();

        break;

    case (R.id.btnSearchShops):

        Intent checkGPS = new Intent("com.example.flybaseapp.CheckGPS");
        startActivity(checkGPS);

        break;

    }

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long idd) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, idd);

    itemId = idd;

    final CharSequence[] items = { "Edit Item", "Delete Item" };

    Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShoppingList.this);

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Item Options:");

    alertDialogBuilder.setItems(items,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                    if (items[item].equals("Edit Item")) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                ShoppingList.this);

                        builder.setTitle("Edit Item");

                        DBHandlerShop setEdit = new DBHandlerShop(
                                ShoppingList.this, null, null);

                        setEdit.open();
                        String itemName = setEdit.getItem(itemId);
                        int itemAmount = setEdit.getItemQuan(itemId);
                        int itemPrice = setEdit.getItemCost(itemId);
                        setEdit.close();

                        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(
                                ShoppingList.this);
                        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                        final EditText titleBox = new EditText(
                                ShoppingList.this);
                        titleBox.setText(itemName);
                        titleBox.setHint("Item Name:");
                        layout.addView(titleBox);

                        final EditText quantityBox = new EditText(
                                ShoppingList.this);
                        quantityBox.setText(Integer.toString(itemAmount));
                        quantityBox.setHint("Item Quantity");
                        layout.addView(quantityBox);

                        final EditText priceBox = new EditText(
                                ShoppingList.this);
                        priceBox.setText(Integer.toString(itemPrice));
                        priceBox.setHint("Item Price.");
                        layout.addView(priceBox);

                        builder.setView(layout);

                        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton) {

                                        Editable valueItem = titleBox
                                                .getText();
                                        Editable valueAmount = quantityBox
                                                .getText();
                                        Editable valuePrice = priceBox
                                                .getText();

                                        String itemDescription = valueItem
                                                .toString();
                                        String s = valueAmount.toString();
                                        int itemAmount = Integer
                                                .parseInt(s);
                                        String a = valuePrice.toString();
                                        int itemPrice = Integer.parseInt(a);

                                        try {
                                            DBHandlerShop update = new DBHandlerShop(
                                                    ShoppingList.this,
                                                    null, null);

                                            int totalCombined = itemAmount
                                                    * itemPrice;

                                            update.open();
                                            update.updateItem(itemId,
                                                    itemDescription,
                                                    itemAmount, itemPrice);
                                            update.close();

                                            int setPrice = updateTotal();
                                            totalPrice.setText(Integer
                                                    .toString(setPrice));

                                        } catch (Exception e) {

                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Items not updated.",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();

                                        } finally {

                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Items updated.",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();

                                            setList();

                                        }

                                    }

                                });

                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton) {

                                    }
                                });

                        builder.show();

                    }

                    else if (items[item].equals("Delete Item")) {
                        try {

                            DBHandlerShop delete = new DBHandlerShop(
                                    ShoppingList.this, null, null);

                            delete.open();
                            delete.deleteItem(itemId);
                            delete.close();

                            DBHandlerShop findPrice = new DBHandlerShop(
                                    ShoppingList.this, null, null);

                            findPrice.open();
                            int returnedCost = findPrice
                                    .getItemCost(itemId);
                            findPrice.close();

                            int cost = updateTotal();

                            int newTotal = cost - returnedCost;
                            totalPrice.setText(Integer.toString(newTotal));
                        }

                        catch (Exception e) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Item failed to be deleted.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        finally {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Item deleted from the list.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            setList();
                        }

                    }

                }

            });

    alertDialogBuilder.show();

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void setList() {

    DBHandlerShop DBShop = new DBHandlerShop(this, null, null);

    DBHandlerShop searchItems = new DBHandlerShop(this, null, null);

    searchItems.open();

    Cursor cursor = searchItems.getItems();

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    searchItems.close();

    String[] from = new String[] { DBShop.KEY_ITEMSHOP, DBShop.KEY_ITEMNUM,
            DBShop.KEY_ITEMPRICE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.txtSetItem, R.id.txtSetAmount,
            R.id.txtSetPrice };

    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.setshoppinglist,
            cursor, from, to);
    showItems.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

}

private int updateTotal() {

    DBHandlerShop total = new DBHandlerShop(this, null, null);

    int totalPrice = 0;
    total.open();
    Cursor totalPrices = total.getTotals();
    total.close();

    if (totalPrices != null) {

        startManagingCursor(totalPrices);
        if (totalPrices.moveToFirst()) {

            do {
                int cost = totalPrices.getInt(3);
                int amount = totalPrices.getInt(2);

                int totalCost = cost * amount;
                totalPrice += totalCost;

            } while (totalPrices.moveToNext());

            return totalPrice;
        }

    }

    else {

        return totalPrice;

    }

    return 0;

}

private void show() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShoppingList.this);

    builder.setTitle("Enter Item Details:");

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    final EditText titleBox = new EditText(this);

    titleBox.setHint("Item Name:");
    layout.addView(titleBox);

    final EditText quantityBox = new EditText(this);

    quantityBox.setHint("Item Quantity");
    layout.addView(quantityBox);

    final EditText priceBox = new EditText(this);

    priceBox.setHint("Item Price.");
    layout.addView(priceBox);

    builder.setView(layout);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            try {

                Editable valueItem = titleBox.getText();
                Editable valueAmount = quantityBox.getText();
                Editable valuePrice = priceBox.getText();

                itemDescription = valueItem.toString();
                String s = valueAmount.toString();
                itemAmount = Integer.parseInt(s);
                String a = valuePrice.toString();
                itemPrice = Integer.parseInt(a);

                DBHandlerShop addItem = new DBHandlerShop(
                        ShoppingList.this, null, null);
                addItem.open();
                addItem.insertItems(itemDescription, itemAmount, itemPrice);
                addItem.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Item failed to be added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } finally {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Item added to your list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                int cost = updateTotal();
                totalPrice.setText(Integer.toString(cost));

                setList();

            }

        }

    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            });

    builder.show();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    setList();

    showItems.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    itemNameEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            showItems.refreshDrawableState();

        }

    });

    getCons = new DBHandlerShop(this, null, null);
    getCons.open();
    cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

            return getCons.getChanges((constraint.toString()));

        }

    });

    showItems.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}

}
```

getChanges() from the Database Handler class:

```
public Cursor getChanges(String constraintPassed) {

        String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWSHOPID, KEY_ITEMSHOP, KEY_ITEMNUM, KEY_ITEMPRICE};
        Cursor c = null;
         if(constraintPassed.equals(""))
         {
             c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLESHOP, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

         }

         else
         {
            c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLESHOP, columns, KEY_ITEMSHOP + " LIKE'" + constraintPassed + "%'", null, null, null, KEY_ITEMSHOP + " ASC", null);
         }

        if( c != null)
            {
                c.moveToFirst();

            }
        return c;
    }
```

Do I need to implement a life-cycle method once the edit has been made? If so could someone push me in the right direction of which is needed as I have tried onResume() and onRestart() to no avail.

Comment: show us more code.....

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar I have added the entire ShoppingList class code.

Comment: How does the `getChanges()` method look like?

Comment: @Luksprog Many thanks for your answer. I have added getChanges(). It is basically used as a method in my Database handler class to return any results from my database that matches the filter term.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your Adapter after you update the filter. This should notify the `ListView` that it needs to refresh its data also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe notifyDataSetChanged(); is now depreciated. I tried this before posting the question and sadly it dosen't work.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. But it is not deprecated. At least it doesn't say so in the docs and doesn't show the deprecated warning in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you are running `getCons.open();` multiple times without closing it or so in between. I don't know whether that `open()` method ignores multiple calls or calling it multiple times causes an error, but you might want to try whether you can fix it by moving `getCons.open();` directly below `getCons = new DBHandlerShop(this, null, null);`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried moving my database .open() methods under my DBHandler object but sadly it still does not filter after an alertdialog & toast message

Answer (score 1):

A simple way around this issue I have found, is to simply recall the class by initiating a new intent object after the edit it complete. This still makes the overall operation of the process smooth and quick, and of course allows me to filter after an edit. So for the time being guys this is how Im going to go with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```
android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:nextFocusUp="@id/editeText1" 
android:nextFocusLeft="@id/edittextText"
android:includeFontPadding="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

I see what is happening in your case. Every time the user successfully edits an item, you are setting a new adapter to your list ! And in your case also, the **TextWatcher** added to your **EditText** in the **onCreate** method is using the very first adapter (in the **onTextChanged** method) also created in the **onCreate** method, the very first time the activity is created !

There are several ways to solve this issue. One way would be to change the whole way you implemented your activity( I personally would not have done it this way ).

Another way would be to simply alter the **setList** method, which is called the very first time in the **onCreate** method, and every time the user successfully edits an item. This is the solution I am going to explain in details since it is quick and easy and NOT time consuming for you :

- If the list does not have a adapter, then create one.
- If the list already has an adapter, then simply change the cursor of the adapter and refresh the list.

So your **setList** method should look like this :

```java
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void setList() {

    DBHandlerShop DBShop = new DBHandlerShop(this, null, null);

    DBHandlerShop searchItems = new DBHandlerShop(this, null, null);

    searchItems.open();

    Cursor cursor = searchItems.getItems();

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    searchItems.close();

    String[] from = new String [] { DBShop.KEY_ITEMSHOP , DBShop.KEY_ITEMNUM, DBShop.KEY_ITEMPRICE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.txtSetItem, R.id.txtSetAmount, R.id.txtSetPrice };

    // Check the cursor adapter is previously created
    if ( cursorAdapter == null ) {
        // There is no previous cursors, create a new one
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.setshoppinglist, cursor, from, to);
        showItems.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    }
    else {
        // There is a previous adapter
        // Stop managing its cursor
        stopManagingCursor ( cursorAdapter.getCursor() );
        // Assign the new cursor to the current adapter
        // The old cursor will be closed
        cursorAdapter.changeCursor ( cursor );
        // No need to refresh the list, it will be automatically refreshed after the adapter's cursor is changed
    }

}
```

In this manner, the adapter of the list is the same one that the **TextWatcher** is using to filter the list. It should work, give it a try and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below changes..

After showing your toast items updated/deleted message call this

```
cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In your setList() method add following..

```
cursorAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
@Override
public void onChanged() {
    super.onChanged();
    setList();
}});
```

and move below code to setList()

```
itemNameEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {

            cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            showItems.refreshDrawableState();

        }

    });

    getCons = new DBHandlerShop(this, null, null);
    getCons.open();
    cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

            return getCons.getChanges((constraint.toString()));

        }

    });
```